# Bootstrap 4 - Readonly Plain Text - Select Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm submitting components in a form dynamically via Ajax, and I want the input components to lose their form styling when the user clicks on the add/save button.

I've managed to do it with the following on a plain text input `$('#ingredientQuantity').attr('readonly', 'readonly').addClass('form-control-plaintext').removeClass('form-control');`

But doing the same with a select doesn't have the same result.

The following is the code:

```
<select required class="custom-select custom-select-lg" id="ingredientUnits">
  <option selected disabled>Select Units</option>
  <option>millilitres</option>
  <option>kilograms</option>
</select>
```

Is there any way to make it look like it's just plain text with either a bootstrap class, or CSS?

Comment: plain text dropdown, do you have any reference or image ?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very clear. I want the input to change once it's saved so that it doesn't look like a dropdown, just plain text. As I say above, you can do it with text inputs - example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#readonly-plain-text)

Comment: are you looking for something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ERWEmV

Comment: I just made it for on change event but you can replace with onclick event with save button

Comment: That will work! If drop it into the answers, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad it work, posted as answer  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of on change event and displaying selected option in p tag and hiding select

```js
$('select').on('change', function(){
  $(this).css('display','none');
  $('.plainText').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select required class="custom-select custom-select-lg" id="ingredientUnits">
  <option selected disabled>Select Units</option>
  <option>millilitres</option>
  <option>kilograms</option>
</select>
<p class="plainText"></p>
```

code sample for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ERWEmV

Comment: Thanks. For my example I changed it to the on click of the save button, but other than that, it worked great.